# Trying to install ggrepel for use with qicharts but getting a non-zero exit status

Tags: r, repository, ggrepel

I was trying to add `library(qicharts)` to my R script. However, when I tried to load it, it told me I needed `ggrepel`. I downloaded the ggrepel archive and tried to install it but I received a warning:

`installation of package [filepath] had a non-zero exit status`

Note the file path was the actual file path but I used a placeholder. The `ggrepel` archive I'm using is "ggrepel_0.6.5.tar.gz".

Comment: `install.packages('ggrepel')` is not enough?

Comment: or the latest version:
`install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("slowkow/ggrepel")`

Comment: @TheBiro `install.packages("ggrepel_0.6.5.tar.gz, repos = NULL, type = "source")` is not good enough.

Comment: @TheBiro also I'm not sure how to do `devtools::install_github("slowkow/ggrepel")` because my machine is not connected to the internet (obviously not this machine lol)

Comment: Hmm so the problem is that you're not able to download direct from internet. So you'll need to add the path to the file like this: `install.packages("C:\\FOLDER\\ggrepel_0.6.5.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")`

Comment: I have the full path in front of the package name already. I just left that out.